# Yii2 + phpstan?

Tags: yii2, phpstan

I have a project (PHP 8.2.6, Yii2, PHPStan). After running phpstan command, I got a list of errors that should be fixed for successful checking. Example of errors:

1. Access to an undefined property `yii\base\Application::$request`.
2. Access to an undefined property `yii\base\Application::$response`.

This errors caused because of use such code:
`Yii::$app->request->post()` or `Yii::$app->response`, etc.

The first solution is to add `/** @phpstan-ignore-next-line */` everywhere in the code where, for example, Yii::$app->response-> will be used.

Question, is there any other proper way to get rid of such errors?

My PHPStan configuration:

```
parameters:
    level: 2
    bootstrapFiles:
        - vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php
    excludePaths:
        - 'runtime/*'
        - 'vendor/*'
        - 'tests/*'
    stubFiles:
        - stubs/ActiveRecord.stub
        - stubs/Yii.stub
        - stubs/YiiRbac.stub
        - stubs/YiiBase.stub
        - stubs/YiiWeb.stub
        - stubs/YiiConsole.stub
    universalObjectCratesClasses:
        - stdClass
```

Answer (score 2):

When debugging problem like these, you should verify what type `Yii::$app` is. You can [troubleshoot types](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/troubleshooting-types):

```php
\PHPStan\dumpType(Yii::$app);
```

Is it what you expect, the actual type `yii\base\Application`? If yes, what makes you believe that `yii\base\Application::$request` property exists? It's probably not declared in a native way on the class. Is it a magic property defined via `__get`? Is there a missing `@property` PHPDoc above the class?

See the helpful article on the topic: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-access-to-undefined-property

If you need to fix wrong 3rd party PHPDocs, you can write a stub file: https://phpstan.org/user-guide/stub-files